# Почему выдает синтаксическую ошибку при создании экземпляра? Как исправить?

Tags: python, классы, syntax

```
class User():
    
    def __init__(self, first_name, last_name):
        self.first_name = first_name
        self.last_name = last_name 
       
    def describe_user(self):
        about_user = f"{self.first_name} {self.last name}"
        print(about_user)
        
    def greet_user(self):
        print(f" Hello {self.first_name.title()} {self.last_name.title()}!") 
        

First = User("AA", "BBBBB")
Second = User("CC", "DDDDD")

First.describe_user()
Second.describe_user()

First.greet_user()
Second.greet_user()
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

на 8 строчке написано `{self.last name}`.

Пробел вместо "_"